# Core dumped when a function pointer is assigned with a funtion that has the same name in another file

Tags: c, function-pointers

I just abstract my problem as a following scenario:
three files:a.h,a.c,b.c,and the code is as below:

a.c

```
#include "a.h"
#include <stdio.h>

int (*call2)();

int call1(int (*cb)()){
    call2=cb;
    printf("success!");
    return 1;
}
```

a.h

```
int call1();
```

b.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "a.h"

int call2(){return 0;};

int main(){
    call1(call2);
}
```

then compiling these files with `gcc a.c b.c -o b` will only get some warings:

```
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: alignment 1 of symbol `call2' in /tmp/cc0wbcYh.o is smaller than 8 in /tmp/ccuDjeEs.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: size of symbol `call2' changed from 8 in /tmp/ccuDjeEs.o to 11 in /tmp/cc0wbcYh.o
/usr/bin/ld: Warning: type of symbol `call2' changed from 1 to 2 in /tmp/cc0wbcYh.o
```

then run it with './b' will get

```
Segmentation fault (core dumped)
```

My ideas:
Apparently, the line `call2=cb;` has caused this corrupt.That means,assigning a function to a function pointer that has the same name is  a wrong operation.I think the reason relates to how the gcc compiler store a function pointer and a function.But I am not familiar with the implementing of gcc compiler.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: I think my question is a bit different with your answer.In my case,I have a variable(function pointer) and a function and they have different type.But your answer deal with a global variable that cross multiple files.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By defining and `call2` as two different objects, with two different types, you have violated the One Definition Rule. The behaviour is undefined.

To achieve the behaviour you want, declare both `call2`'s `static` so they have internal linkage and don't conflict with each other.